# Extract all element of a list that matched a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a keyword list and an input list of lists. My task is to find those lists that contain the keyword (even partially). I am able to extract the lists that contain the keyword using the following code:

```py
t_list = [['Subtotal: ', '1,292.80 '], ['VAT ', ' 64.64 '], ['RECEIPT TOTAL ', 'AED1,357.44 '],  
          ['NOT_SELECTED, upto2,000 ', 'Sub total ', '60.58 '], 
          ['NOT_SELECTED, upto500 ', 'amount 160.58 ', '', '3.03 '],
          ['Learn', 'Bectricity total ', '', '', '63.61 ']]

keyword = ['total ', 'amount ']

for lists in t_list:
    for string_list in table:
        string_list[:] = [item for item in string_list if item != '']
            for element in string_list:
                element = element.lower()
                if any(s in element for s in keyword):
                    print(string_list)

The output is:
 [['Subtotal: ', '1,292.80 '], ['RECEIPT TOTAL ', 'AED1,357.44 '], ['NOT_SELECTED, upto2,000 ', 'Sub total ', '60.58 '], ['NOT_SELECTED, upto500 ', 'amount 160.58 ', '3.03 '],
          ['Learn', 'Bectricity total ', '63.61 ']]
```

Required output is to have only the string that matched with the keyword and the number in the list.

Required output:

```py
[['Subtotal: ', '1,292.80 '], ['RECEIPT TOTAL ', 'AED1,357.44 '], ['Sub total ', '60.58 '], ['amount 160.58 ', '3.03 '],['Bectricity total ', '63.61 ']]
```

If I can have the output as a dictionary with the string matched to the keyword as key and the number a value, it would be perfect.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: I am a little confused by this question. A lot of those lists seem quite random. So you are checking if any of the elements in that list match a keyword, but then which number do you want? Only a number that appears in the same string that matched the keyword? Or any numbers that are in that list? For example in the 'NOT_SELECTED, upto500' list, there are 2 numbers (3 if you count the 500), which number do you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain the steps:

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain the steps:  Step 1 :  to search for keywords in ```t_list``` and return the element which matched the keyword and the digit that is present in the list. From ```['NOT_SELECTED, upto500', 'amount 160.58 ', '3.03 ']```, I want ```['amount 160.58 ', '3.03 ']```. The first element because of keyword amount and the number '3.03' as it is a digit. @RolvApneseth

Comment: So is the last item in each list always the number you want? Because for example how does `'AED1,357.44 '` count

Comment: That is not always the case. If somehow I can get the element that matched my keyword and all the elements that have numbers. I can work with that @RolvApneseth

Comment: This would include things like `NOT_SELECTED, upto500` is that ok?

Comment: according to me, that is the best than can be done. Would you like to know more about the problem? We can do that in the chat @RolvApneseth

Comment: Yes let's move to chat I have an answer that might be what you want

Comment: My bad. I don't have enough reputation for that @RolvApneseth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227586/discussion-between-m-arora-and-rolv-apneseth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from our chat, slightly modified with some comments as some explanation for the code. Feel free to ask me to clarify or change anything.

```
import re

t_list = [
    ['Subtotal: ', '1,292.80 '],
    ['VAT ', ' 64.64 '],
    ['RECEIPT TOTAL ', 'AED1,357.44 '],
    ['NOT_SELECTED, upto2,000 ', 'Sub total ', '60.58 '],
    ['NOT_SELECTED, upto500 ', 'amount 160.58 ', '', '3.03 '],
    ['Learn', 'Bectricity total ', '', '', '63.61 ']
]

keywords = ['total ', 'amount ']

output = {}

for sub_list in t_list:
    # Becomes the string that matched the keyword if one is found
    matched = None

    for item in sub_list:
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in item.lower():
                matched = item

    # If a match was found, then we start looking at the list again
    # looking for the numbers
    if matched:
        for item in sub_list:
            # split the string so for example 'amount 160.58 ' becomes ['amount', '160.58']
            # This allows us to more easily extract just the number
            split_items = item.split()
            for split_item in split_items:
                # Simple use of regex to match any '.' with digits either side
                re_search = re.search(r'[0-9][.][0-9]', split_item)
                if re_search:
                    # Try block because we are making a list. If the list exists, 
                    # then just append a value, otherwise create the list with the item
                    # in it
                    try:
                        output[matched.strip()].append(split_item)
                    except KeyError:
                        output[matched.strip()] = [split_item]

print(output)
```

You mentioned wanting to match a string such as `'AED 63.61'`. My solution is using `.split()` to separate strings and make it easier to grab just the number. For example, for a string like `'amount 160.58'` it becomes much easier to just grab the `160.58`. I'm not sure how to go about matching a string like the one you want to keep but not matching the one I just mentioned (unless, of course, it is just `'AED'` in which case we could just add some more logic to match anything with `'aed'`).